# Why can't gdb find the address of a stack variable

Tags: gdb

I am getting the following from gdb:

[image]

Below is the source of the program and the tutorial it came from. BAsed on what is going on in the tutorial, I should not be getting an error.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = a + 6;
    return b;
}
```

https://www.hackerschool.com/blog/7-understanding-c-by-learning-assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need debugging symbols for the variable names to be defined in GDB. Did you compile with the `-g` switch?

Comment: Yes, and after compiling it again it worked fine.

Comment: You mean the debugging or the program worked? If the debugging is working as you wanted please mark this question as solved.